# Why isn't my div staying in the wrapper's height?

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I was wondering if anyone could point in the direction of a solution!
For some reason my rightbar's height isn't staying within the parent div (mainwrapper), and I have the body and the wrapper's height set to 100%.

When I set it to 90% it fits but then when I resize the window to anything lower than 1920x1080, it goes out of the wrapper again.

Any and all would be appreciated!

I read online somewhere that it's usually floating divs that cause this, but I have nothing floating and I believe I have the corrent position:relative placed.

I've not worded this the best with "bar", so here's a gyazo image to hopefully help with this: https://gyazo.com/6661da9c5194e2c2619e5fe1b5e3f2c5 - As you can see, the bar goes out of the wrapper when set to 100%

My code:

```css
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(/css/images/backgroundimages/bgimg.png);
}

div#mainwrapper {
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-left: 4px solid #000;
border-right: 4px solid #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

div#menubar {
background-color: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.2);
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

div#menubar a {
text-align: center;
padding: 31px;
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
text-shadow: 2px 4px 7px #000;
}
div#menubar a:hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
padding: 30px;
font-size: 1.3em;
transition: 0.3s;
color: rgba(231, 76, 60, 1.0);
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
font-weight: bold;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

div#maincontent {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

div#rightbar {
width: 15%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainwrapper">
    <div id="menubar">
        <a href="index.php">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">FRIENDS</a>
        <a href="#">FORUM</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="rightbar">
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `div#menubar:hover {}` for?

Comment: It's just there for when I go ahead and add some background effects to the menu bar.

Comment: For future questions, please try to boil down your code to the absolute minimum necessary. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: No CSS for `div#maincontent`?

Comment: No, because there's nothing in main content yet, I'm trying to get the right bar sorted first, but the height doesn't stay inside the wrapper...

Comment: How about putting `display: inline-block` on your `.menuBar a` selector?

Comment: @balapa, Unfortunately didn't work, it just made the bar bigger.

Comment: If I add position:absolute to the div#menubar, it fixes the issue, however it messes up the width of the bar

Comment: You see that useless code in your sample just produces unnecessary questions. Remove all that!

Comment: @AceyWolf ah sorry, i think i missed the context, try `height: 100%` on the `html` selector

Comment: I've added a gyazo link to better show when I'm trying to explain... hopefully it clears up some confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Try erasing the `height: 100%;` on `div#rightbar` and replace it with `min-height: calc(100vh - 85px);`


The reasoning: `100vh` means '100% viewport height'. So whatever the height of your browser window is the height `#rightbar` will be. But you need to subtract the height of `#menubar` from it (85px). `calc()` helps you accomplish this. Take a note of this css property/value combo because you'll potentially use it a lot for making your footers stick to the bottom of the page (AKA 'sticky footers'). Make sure you have a space on either side of the `-` sign. If you don't include those spaces, the `calc()` function won't work.

**OLD ANSWER:** <s>I apologize if I don't understand what you're wanting, but I'll give it a shot: `#rightbar`'s height actually is inside of the wrapper - it's just not inside the border that you created around `#menubar`.</s>

Erase `border-bottom: 4px solid #000;` from `div#menubar` and move it to `div#mainwrapper` instead. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ms2e2e5v/1/

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6661da9c5194e2c2619e5fe1b5e3f2c5   - This is the bar I mean, which I've labelled as "rightbar", but as you can see by the image the height doesn't stay within the wrapper

Comment: So is your problem that you can't get `div#rightbar` to meet the bottom of the page? That's what I think I'm seeing in the picture.
The code snippet you posted doesn't seem to translate your problem well. Can you re post your code with as close to the code in that gyazo picture as you can? I know you got discouraged from doing so earlier but in the case of a personal glitch it actually helps us to have everything. Currently when we run your code snippet we can't even see `div#rightbar` unless we place content in their ourselves, and even then we can't see the problem unless we fill the page.

Comment: EDIT, okay, I see what you're saying (#rightbar on the left side of the page overlapping at the bottom). I'll try to figure it out. It's a little difficult because the code snippet you posted doesn't show the problem (@ bottom of the window).

Comment: I've edited the code to what I have now, but something in the back of mind just clicked and maybe it's because I'm using padding to define the height for the menubar, and not a set height, so it's pushing the rightbar further than it should? I think that might be the issue, I'll get back to you!

Comment: Ok, so that wasn't the issue, even with a define height on menubar, it still goes out of the wrapper

Comment: I'm not sure why the snippet isn't showing it, but I've uploaded the files to my webhost so you can see the issue: http://aceywolf.esy.es/

Comment: I gave you a quick hack which I believe fixes it, if you go up and look at the top of my original answer where it says **edit**. I'll keep looking for perhaps a better solution but for now I think that fixes it.

Comment: No worries, I changed it slightly to 85px (it looks like you may have changed the height of #menubar) from 87px to 85px. Basically, whatever the height of #menubar, thats what you subtract from 100vh.  If by chance it doesn't work like you want it to as you add stuff, post here and I'll see your post notification and help you out.